# The best plotting package in javascript?

Tags: javascript, plotting

Would you please help me to find the most professional looking, comprehensive plotting package in javascript? I'm looking for somtething equivalent to python matplotlib in javascript.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. Also, [what's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185). You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details, and **[edit]** your question – which will increase your chances for good and matching answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) renders onto the Browser's [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API), whereas [highcharts.js](https://www.highcharts.com/) and [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) create [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) output (which is XML).

All create great output.

Choosing the output format according to your needs and preferences is just one of many  key tech decisions you must make, and a question only you can answer.